# identifying button element on a webpage selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I am trying to locate a pesky button on my webpage.  most of the other elements I can locate but this one is giving me a headache.

The html is:

```
<table class="d_FG" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="z_t">
<td class="fct_w" colspan="2">
<div>
<input name="newAttachments_fsid" value="0" type="hidden">
<table id="z_u" class="dcs" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr style="border: none;">
<td colspan="3" style="padding-right:0">
<a id="z_v" class="vui-button d2l-button d2l_1_192_930" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Add a File</a>
<a id="z_w" class="vui-button d2l-button d2l_1_193_372" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Record Audio</a>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

I am trying to locate the element:

```
<a id="z_v" class="vui-button d2l-button d2l_1_192_930" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Add a File</a>
```

I have tried various methods such as:

```
    public void add_attachment(){
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("z_v"))).click();

}
```

But just cant manage it.  Always get the message it is not visible or another element would be clicked.

I tried using a javascript that scrolls down to the element but that didn't work.  Any ideas to help me with would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try some other workarounds like using `Actions` or `javascriptExecutor` as below,

```
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("z_v")));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(btn).build.perform();
```

or

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",btn);
```

Comment: I did try something like that already, but when I go back to work tomorrow I will try ur exact method. Perhaps when I tried the JavaScript method I did it incorrectly. Thanks I'll let you know it it works

Comment: Brilliant, I tried the second method and it works.  The first method didnt somehow press the button to open the attach file popup window,  I dont really understand how the second version works or why my original version and your first suggestion didnt work.  If you could walk through that it would be appreciated(if you have time).